# Need assistance with Wordpress mobile redirect code

Tags: wordpress, redirect, mobile

I am attempting to find a solution to redirect a single page from my WordPress website to a mobile version (I do not want to redirect all mobile users for all my pages to a different page or theme, only just a single page).  With some help from the stackoverflow community, I currently have the following code (utilizing detectmobilebrowsers.com to help with the redirect) and am using it as a plugin in Wordpress, however it's not currently working.  I think the code needs a little work, so any help you could provide would be most appreciated!  Keep in mind I'm a newbie with coding :-)  Thanks!

-----UPDATE-----

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_so_19285382' );

function redirect_so_19472213() 
{
if ( !is_page( 2766 ) )
        return;

if( is_mobile_detectmobilebrowsers_com() ) 
{ 
    wp_redirect( 'http://lifebyjohn.com/mobile-schedule' ); 
    exit(); 
}
}

function is_mobile_detectmobilebrowsers_com()
{
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
return 
preg_match(     '/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i', $useragent ) 
|| preg_match( '/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i', substr( $useragent,0,4 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with [**`site_url`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)<sup>*</sup>, it doesn't take a full path.

You can either do:

```
wp_redirect( site_url( 'mobile-schedule' ) );
```

or simply:

```
wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/mobile-schedule' );
```

<sub><sub>`*` *The Codex is our friend, always check the Codex :)*</sub></sub>

And you're redirecting *every* page that **is not** `2766` to the mobile page, in essence, all your site is redirecting to the mobile page, including the mobile page itself, loopsss... :)

I suppose page `2766` is the Non-Mobile version: `http://example.com/schedule`. So, **if not** our page, do nothing:

```
if( !is_page( 2276 ) ) // <--- note the exclamation, that means NOT
```

---

I just tried the following plugin in my site and works ok with my iPhone. I left out the function `is_mobile_detectmobilebrowsers_com`, it's still same.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Redirect One Page
 */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_so_19472213' );

function redirect_so_19472213() 
{
    if ( !is_page( 2276 ) )
            return;

    if( is_mobile_detectmobilebrowsers_com() ) 
    { 
        wp_redirect( 'http://lifebyjohn.com/mobile-schedule' ); 
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, made the edits you suggested, and two things are happening: one, getting a "too many redirects" error, and two, its trying to redirect me from every page (not just when I'm on page 2766, which is http://lifebyjohn.com/schedule). I know this is the case since just going to the home page, for example, then ends up looking life http://lifebyjohn.com/mobile-schedule, and then it gives me the "too many redirects" error.  Help!  :-)

Comment: Any thoughts by chance?  :-)

Comment: Okay, I saw your edits above and that makes complete sense.  I also tried your test site and it works perfectly on my iPhone as well.  I've updated my code above per your edits, however even though I'm not getting any errors any longer, it's just simply not working.  First, can you check my code above with a fine toothed comb, and second, can you post the entirety of the code you're using on your test site, since that's working great?  I think we're getting very close!  Thanks!